# text/HTML editor component for Flex 3

Tags: flex3

I am looking for a simple HTML Editor component in Flex-3.
I tried googling but could not find any proper component which are ready-to-use.

My requirement is -

```
1. The Editor should support text and HTML.
2. There should be a preview window as well.
```

Thanks ,
Miral

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something for Flex webapps, then you may take a look at,

`http://dgrigg.com/blog/2009/12/23/flex-wysiwyg-html-editor/`

If you are looking for an AIR application, you can try loading FCKEditor/CKEditor in an HTML control, and then wiring up using the AIR/HTML/JS bridge to do what you want. I have used the same in one of my business projects, but due to employer restrictions cannot share the code.

However, I am trying to create a pure Flex HTML editor control (it works for few functionalities) on top the AIR HTML control, harnessing the WebKit power. It includes both the source and preview modes. The code for the same (still in development) is checked in at,

```
http://jerry.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jerry/as3rte/
```

You are free to contribute to the above code if you like.

Comment: I am looking for flex webapps, and the prototype link is not working currently. Is the source code open to use?

Comment: Yes Miral. The prototype link should have opened, the code is checked in. Alternately, you may use the github URL at https://github.com/myjerry/as3rte and browse the entire code base.